# What is the cause of this Umbrella Exception

Tags: java, exception, gwt

The application is loading in the browser, however it is throwing exceptions which says

> 11:59:49.770 [ERROR] [loginform] Uncaught exception escaped
>   com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions
>   caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
>       at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:129)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)

What is the cause and how to resolve this?

Comment: The real cause is logged, update and provide full stacktrace. (Perhaps you need to use GWT devMode)

Comment: See your GWT layout. Debug it. Any exception thrown in your layout will be embraced with umbrella exception.

Comment: @YegoshinMaxim Exception **com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:129)** pointing to _HandlerManager Class_ at **throw new UmbrellaException(e.getCauses());**

Comment: What you pointed out - is not the real case. 
Exception may be thrown somewhere in your gwt layout code, for example NPE when working with non-initialized variable. And it become an UmbrellaException in your browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the interesting part. Create an uncaught exception-handler,
[like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028521/gwt-setuncaughtexceptionhandler).
**update:**

As you can see here: [GWT/JAVA Uncaught exception escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343483/gwt-java-uncaught-exception-escaped)

The Stacktrace should be longer. There is a root-cause atatched to the Umbrella-Exception.

Answer (score 3):

Try to resolve errors happened in your application. I've already answered the same question [GWT client umbrellaexception get full error message in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029002/gwt-client-umbrellaexception-get-full-error-message-in-java/11033699#11033699)

Answer (score 0):

I am from future) I had same problem today. I just foggot to add .js folder in project and a few lines of code to "yourModule".html file. See instalation guide here: http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/userguide.jsp#installation